# Embedding an aspx page with a silverlight application in another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight

In short:

How to dynamically embed an aspx page (`MyAppHost.aspx`) in another page (`Default.aspx`). `MyAppHost.aspx` hosts a silverlight application that reads query string from `AppHost.aspx`

In more detail:

I had the requirement to dynamically create a graphic (bitmap) based on the selections on the page `Default.aspx`. I did that as shown below in `Default.aspx.cs`:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/MakeImage.aspx?param1=" + 
Param1.ToString() + "&param2=" Param2.ToString();
```

In `MakeImage.aspx`:

```
image.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This is working fine. I have made changes to the project to make use of silverlight to generate the graphics. My Silverlight application is embedded in a test (default) aspx page (`MyAppHost.aspx`) and it is designed to accept query string from `MyAppHost.aspx` as shown below.

In `MyApp.xaml.cs`,  I have

```
if (HtmlPage.Document.QueryString.ContainsKey("param1"))
{
        Param1 = HtmlPage.Document.QueryString["param1"];
}
```

I need to dynamically embed the Silverlight app, `MyApp` (with the host `MyAppHost.aspx?param1={0}&param2={1}`) in `Default.aspx` based on the user selections in `Default.aspx`. How is that possible?

EDIT:
As suggested, it would be a lot more easier if I can host the silverlight app in `Default.aspx` itself and use init parameters and not query strings. I had thought about the approach, but could not figure out how to pass parameters on an event dynamically. I am adding [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859045/load-a-silverlight-application-to-aspx-page-with-initparameters).

Comment: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838145(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: That does not apply in my case. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: If the Silverlight app is reliant on the MyAppHost.aspx page, what about loading it in an iframe on Default.aspx?

Comment: can I do it dynamically on click of a button in Default.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

Your only option to do exactly what you are asking is to use client site JavaScript code to insert IFrame with url pointing to your MyAooHost.aspx page on original page as needed.

It may be easier approach to make your Silverlight control to accept input from the page's script intead of reading parameters from the query string - this way you just need to add your SL control to original page and update properties when user selection changes (much faster than reloading frame with SL control).

Comment: Yes, that approach would be easier. The parameters to be passed to the silverlight application is generated based on user inputs in `Default.aspx` page. Any idea how to dynamically load a silverlight application with `InitParameters` based on user selections.

Comment: These articles should cover it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28v=VS.95%29.aspx