# Load a silverlight to aspx page through code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight

I need to load a silverlight application in a portion of an aspx page on a button click on that page page. Some init parameters need to be passed to the silverlight application based on the user inputs on the host page on button click. How to do that?

I presume I need to create the silverlight object from code-behind to set custom InitParameters. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Extending to what is mentioned [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/133036/297460.aspx), you can do something like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl myHtmlObject = new HtmlGenericControl("object");
myHtmlObject.Attributes["data"] = "data:application/x-silverlight-2";
myHtmlObject.Attributes["type"] = "application/x-silverlight-2";
myHtmlObject.Attributes["width"] = "100%";
myHtmlObject.Attributes["height"] = "100%";
this.Page.Controls.Add(myHtmlObject);

HtmlGenericControl mySourceParam = new HtmlGenericControl("param");
mySourceParam.Attributes["name"] = "source";
mySourceParam.Attributes["value"] = "ClientBin/MySilverlightApplication.xap";
myHtmlObject.Controls.Add(mySourceParam);

HtmlGenericControl myOnErrorParam = new HtmlGenericControl("param");
myOnErrorParam .Attributes["name"] = "onError";
myOnErrorParam .Attributes["value"] = "onSilverlightError";
myHtmlObject.Controls.Add(myOnErrorParam);

HtmlGenericControl myInputParam = new HtmlGenericControl("param");
myOnErrorParam .Attributes["name"] = "InitParameters";
myOnErrorParam .Attributes["value"] = "param1=Hello,param2=World";
myHtmlObject.Controls.Add(myInputParam);

this.Page.Controls.Add(myHtmlObject);
```